# How to edit (particularly flip direction of) polyline obtained through UpdateCursor?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, arcpy, line

I want to flip the direction of a polyline feature obtained as a result of an Update query; e.g.

```
lines= arcpy.UpdateCursor(myFeatureClass,myQuery)
dsc= arcpy.Describe(myFeatureClass)
try:
    for ln in lines:
        # ? Check number of parts
        # ? Flip direction of each, or some of the parts
        lines.updateRow(ln)
except:
    print "Error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
finally:
    # releasing locks
    if lines: del lines
    if ln: del ln
```

BTW, any better way to know how many rows are returned than counting them?

Comment: I figured that ln.shape is the key to the geometry class I am interested in, e.g. if I want to check if it is multi-part, I can check ln.shape.isMultipart

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just for the record, and to help the folks who might be looking:

```
def flipLine(myFeatureClass, myQuery):
    try:
        lines=arcpy.UpdateCursor(myFeatureClass, myQuery)
        dsc=arcpy.Describe(myFeatureClass)
        lc=0
        for ln in lines:
            if ln.shape.partCount > 1: 
                print "Warning: multiple parts! extra parts are automatically trimmed!"
            lp= ln.shape.getPart(0)
            rPnts=arcpy.Array()
            for i in range(len(lp)): rPnts.append(lp[len(lp)-i-1])
            rPoly=arcpy.Polyline(rPnts)
            ln.shape= rPoly
            lines.updateRow(ln)
    except:
        print "Error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
    finally:
        if lines: del lines
        if ln: del ln
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Get Count](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0017000000n7000000) to get the number of rows.

```py
#Need to use .getOutput(0) to extract the value from the result object.
#Value is a string, so cast to int.
result = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(lyrfile).getOutput(0))
```

There is a tool, [Flip Line](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001v00000005000000.htm) that modifies the input. But if you want to use UpdateCursor, one way to do it would be to write the coordinates of all the vertices to a list of lists and then write them back to the lines in reverse.

If you are using ArcMap 10.1, definitely make the swap to the [data access module](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000008000000). It's faster and has better support for accessing the geometry of features.