# Flipping multiple lines in Arcmap 10.4 (Basic Package)

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.4, basic-license-level

I am working on a detailed stream edit and noticed that there are a lot of streams that need to be flipped due to the flow being incorrect based on direction. I was wondering if there was a script that someone had where I could achieve this task?
And if so, can you describe to me how it works? My Python is a little rusty.

I am running ArcMap Basic so I don't have any extensions that I'm used to, otherwise this wouldn't be much of an issue.

Comment: You would have to [read the line geometry](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/reading-geometries.htm), resort the vertices, and [rewrite the geometry](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/writing-geometries.htm).  What have you tried?

Comment: Are your stream line data stored as a PolylineZ?  If so, I have a script that will flip those lines to ensure the line direction conforms to the z values of the start and end nodes.

Comment: Without regard to retaining z-vals in orig order, this answer (a Python flipLine function) loads each line into a point array, reverses the orientation, and reloads into a new geometry object to use in updating your current geometry...just have to be careful because it operates on orig fc (make a copy of your fc to experiment):  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67413/how-to-edit-particularly-flip-direction-of-polyline-obtained-through-updatecur

Comment: Depending upon the network topology, i.e. are there loops or is it a raster derived river network, then have a look at [RivEX](http://www.rivex.co.uk/Online-Manual/Reorientateanetworktoflowtomouth.html), it has a tool for flipping lines within a catchment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all the replies people! I don't have the budget to buy other programs or anything but I've filed them in my mind for later on when I do!
I found the answer to my issue at: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/168001

The code that I used that did what I needed was from user **Darren Wiens** who had answered someone else's question about this same issue.

```py
fc = "line"  
sr = arcpy.Describe(fc).spatialReference  
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,"SHAPE@",spatial_reference=sr) as cursor:  
    for row in cursor:  
        vertices = []  
        for part in row[0]:  
            for pnt in part:  
                print type(pnt)  
                vertices.append(pnt)  
        row[0] = arcpy.Polyline(arcpy.Array(vertices[::-1]))  
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

In this you just change "line" to whatever your feature name is and it flips the end and beginning nodes of the polylines. Just be aware that this script will make changes directly to your feature class, so to be safe you should make a back-up.

Maybe it looks weird to "answer my own question" but this is just in case someone else runs into this issue.

Comment: You are allowed to answer your own question. You should summarize the results of the geonet results here in case that link is no longer valid.

Comment: I added <!-- language: lang-py --> to make the code block look better.