# How do I Identify and flip the lines from source to the destination solution in ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, network-analyst

I have got cable network data and I wanted to know if there is any way to flip all the lines in such a way that start (FROM) point should be the source which is direction of current.

Red labels are cable numbers. Circled blue lines need to be flipped, they have got 'arrow at the end' symbology.
[image]

Is there any solution to flip all of the lines in such a way that they are carrying electricity from source to the next cable.  Possible to find network analyst functions in arcmap or something in python

Comment: Are you using a geometric network?

Comment: These are just polyline data at the moment, and haven't used geometric network yet

Comment: Arcmap's Network Analyst doesn't use geometric networks AFAIK.  Typically you'd used the Utility Network Analyst toolbar in arcmap to see flow arrows in a geometric network.  The toolbar does _not_ work with Network Datasets or Esri's new #UtilityNetwork.  Yes, this is confusing.

Comment: See also https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/263399/59

Comment: At the moment you have a tag for Python and whether that represents ArcPy or another Python library for questions seeking help with writing code please always provide a code attempt.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.