# How to select trenches only upstream of a station (select by location)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, select-by-location

I have a shape (line) that represents the hydromorphology of watercourses  and contains several parameters. This morphological study of watercourses has been done on every 100 meters of surface watercourses.

In other side, I have another shape (point) with measurement stations that is superimposed on the watercourses.

For a specific analysis, I need 10 trenches (1000 m) in the upstream of each station to calculate the average of certain parameters.

I did a select by location with the method (are whithin a distance of the source layer feature), but it gives me a selection of 10 trenches in upstream and downstream of the measurement stations.

Anyone have a solution for having 10 trenches in upstream of each station only of the measurement stations?
[image]

The id's of trenches are not coded in a logical sequence.

[image]

The lines are connected to each other and flow in the source direction

[image]

Comment: Are your trenches coded with an ID in a logical sequence (if not you should be asking yourself why not?). For example your station intersects trench 66 then you need only do an attribute selection of trenches 56 to 66. This could all be automated in model builder.

Comment: No, the id's of trenches are not coded in a logical sequence. The shape of this trenches are done by other part.

Comment: Are the lines connected to each other at their ends and always flow in a source to sea direction?

Comment: Also I think you should amend your question and add that imagine from your deleted answer as that holds vital information about attribution which people need if they are going to answer your question. As you see I am having to ask questions because you have basically provided no information about your data, just a problem with processing. Well described questions attract answers.

Comment: @Hornbydd, thanks you for your questions. yes the lines are connected to each other at their ends and flow in the source direction.

Comment: So your lines are essentially flowing upstream? Traditionally and more importantly for network analysis they should be flowing in a source to sea direction, i.e downstream. The first thing I would do is flip your lines.This [Q&A](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67413/how-to-edit-particularly-flip-direction-of-polyline-obtained-through-updatecur) shows some python code to do that.

Comment: There are tools like RivEX designed specifically to process river networks, it can generate reaches u/s and d/s which you could then use to select the underlying network elements (your trenches). A video showing you how to use define a d/s reach is [here](http://www.rivex.co.uk/Online-Manual/VideoWalkthroughs.html#Reach) in it's help file, but your network must conform to [these specifications](http://www.rivex.co.uk/html/network-specifications.html).

Comment: I tried the copy demonstration, but I still have a error message "geometry can not have Z values", But there is no Z value in the sites table. and there are two layers that are created in the output folder but they are empty